# Led powered solar panels?

Tags: solar-power

I've read multiple threads about this but I've yet to come across an answer to this question.... would it be possible to have a small bank of led lights power multiple solar panels? For instance, if I were to build a dome of solar panels facing inward toward a few led lights placed on the bottom of the dome, would that be enough to power anything substantial? I understand that most solar or panels are only about 15% efficient but could this design offset that efficiency rating to produce more power than it actually uses?